# Here is a piece of code that converts all .csv files in a folder to .xls every minute. But I seeking some help to avoid duplication

Tags: vbscript

Here is a piece of code that converts all .csv files in a folder to .xls every minute. But I am seeking some help to avoid duplication. In other words, according to the flow it seeks all .CSV files in a certain folder and it saves them as .XLS in the exact same folder. In a loop it continue doing so every minute. Now the files that are already converted once dosnt need to be converted again. So I am seeking some help to add an extra logic to it as described below.

For each file in a folder, if file extension is .CSV check if the same file name with extension .XLS exist in the same folder. If it does then check the same for the next file, else SAVE that file AS .XLS. and do the same for all the remaining files in that folder.

```
Dim waittime : waittime = 1 * 60 * 1000
'Constants
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51             '(without macro's in 2007-2016, xlsx)
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = 52 '(with or without macro's in 2007-2016, xlsm)
Const xlExcel12 = 50                     '(Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2016 with or without macro's, xlsb)
Const xlExcel8 = 56
Const xlExcEL9795 = 43

Do
    ' Extensions for old and new files
    strExcel = "xls"
    strCSV = "csv"

    ' Set up filesystem object for usage
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' Access the folder to process
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\User\Desktop\CSV to XLS\")

    ' Load Excel (hidden) for conversions
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = False
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

    ' Process all files
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        ' Get full path to file
        strPath = objFile.Path
        ' Only convert CSV files
        If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(strPath)) = LCase(strCSV) Then
            ' Display to console each file being converted
            'WScript.Echo "Converting """ & strPath & """"
            ' Load CSV into Excel and save as native Excel file
            Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPath, False, True)
            objWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(strPath, strCSV, strExcel), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            objWorkbook.Close False
            Set objWorkbook = Nothing
        End If
    Next

    WScript.Sleep(waittime)
Loop
```

Comment: Just start writing the code and come back when you get stuck somewhere. You can't expect someone to do your work for you (unless you pay them of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to check if a file with the same basename but a different extension exists in the same directory and do the conversion only if that is not the case.

```
If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(strPath)) = LCase(strCSV) Then
    directory = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(strPath)
    basename  = objFSO.GetBaseName(strPath)
    xlsPath   = objFSO.BuildPath(directory, basename & "." & strExcel)

    If Not objFSO.FileExists(xlsPath) Then
        Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPath, False, True)
        objWorkbook.SaveAs xlsPath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        objWorkbook.Close False
        Set objWorkbook = Nothing
    End If
End If
```